# Student scores array, average function not implementing

Tags: javascript

I have an assignment for my first JavaScript class to create an application that takes the last name, first name, and score as input for a student. The app should keep a running average of the scores and provide a button to clear the scores, as well as a button to sort by last name. I have everything working except for the average function. I wrote it, but it isn't implementing. I may be missing something completely simple. I would really appreciate any assistance that you could offer. Thank you for your time!

.js file:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

//the dreaded $ variable

var grades = [];
//array

//update scores with scores, first, last, sort by last
var update_scores = function () {
        var val = get_item_list(grades);
        $("scores").value = val;
        $("last_name").value = "";
        $("first_name").value = "";
        $("score").value = "";
        $("last_name").focus();
    }
    //function to add last, first, score to studentGrade
var student_grade_add_click = function () {


    var last = $("last_name").value;
    var first = $('first_name').value;
    var score = parseFloat($('score').value);

    grades.push([last, first, score]);
    update_scores();
}


var get_item_list = function (item_list) {
    if (item_list.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    var list = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < item_list.length; i++) {
        var current = item_list[i];
        for (var attribute in current) {
            list += current[attribute] + ", ";
        }
        list += "\n";
    }
    return list;
}

//average function
function getAverageScore(grades) { //function-takes grades array
    var i; //declare variable
    var numberOfStudents = grades.length; //declare variable along length  of array for number of students
    var sum = 0; //set sum to zero
    if (numberStudents > 0) { // step through grades if > 0 students
        for (i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) { //increment by 1 through grades
            sum += grades[i][2]; //add each score to sum
        }
        return sum / numberOfStudents; //divide total of sum by how many students
    }
    return 0; // if no students, return 0
}

function clear_click() {
    $("form").reset();

    grades.splice(0, grades.length); //TO CLEAR ARRAY AS WELL AS FORM
}

var sort_click = function () //ENTIRE FUNCTION TO SORT ARRAY AND REPRINT
    {
        grades.sort();
        update_scores();
    }

window.onload = function () {

    $("add_button").onclick = student_grade_add_click;
    $("sort_button").onclick = sort_click;
    $("last_name").focus();
}
```

And here is my .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Part 4</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scores.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scores.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Molengo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Student Scores</h1>
    <div class="formLayout">
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="last_name"/><br/>

        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="first_name"/><br/>

        <label>Score:</label>
        <input type="text" id="score"/><br/>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="add_button" value="Add Student Score"/><br/>
    </div>
    <h2>Student Scores</h2>
<form id = "form">
    <p><textarea id="scores" rows="5" cols="60" disabled="disabled"></textarea></p>
</form>
    <div class="formLayout">
        <label>Average score:</label>
        <input type="text" id="average_score" disabled="disabled"/><br/>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear Student Scores" onclick="clear_click()"/><br/>

        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="button" id="sort_button" value="Sort By Last Name"/><br/>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of all that `...value = '';` stuff, have you considered putting the form controls in a form and using *reset*?

Comment: You have `var numberOfStudents ...` then `if (numberStudents`, *numberOfStudents* is not *numberStudents*. :-)

Comment: I don't see you using `getAverageScore` function anywhere.

Comment: So, fix typos and update your update_score() function with:  $('average_score').value=getAverageScore(grades);, and script will work. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have not called the function `getAverageScore(grades)`. So simply add the call in update_scores function

```
var update_scores = function () {
    var val = get_item_list(grades);
    $("scores").value = val;
    $("last_name").value = "";
    $("first_name").value = "";
    $("score").value = "";
    $("last_name").focus();
    $("average_score").value = getAverageScore(grades);
}
```

and in the `getAverageScore(grades)` function, the variable is `numberOfStudents` instead of `numberStudents` in the `if` condition.

```
function getAverageScore(grades) { //function-takes grades array
var i; //declare variable
var numberOfStudents = grades.length; //declare variable along length  of array for number of students
var sum = 0; //set sum to zero
if (numberOfStudents > 0) { // step through grades if > 0 students
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) { //increment by 1 through grades
        sum += grades[i][2]; //add each score to sum
    }
    return sum / numberOfStudents; //divide total of sum by how many students
}
return 0; }
```

After these modifications, the code works fine !